# Lipschitz constant after a Gaussian Convolution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution, lipschitz-functions

Given a probability distribution $p(x)$ over the whole $\mathbb{R}$, that is $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \quad p(x) > 0$, which has a finite Lipschitz constant $L$ we construct a "blurred" distribution using a Gaussian convolution. Assuming that $f(\epsilon)$ is a Gaussian probability density function with variance $\sigma^2$ the resulting distribution is:
$$ \tilde{p}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x - \epsilon) f(\epsilon) d \epsilon$$

Intuitively it seems that the Lipschitz constant of $\tilde{p}(x)$ is going to be smaller compared to $L$ (you can prove this mathematically). My question is for a general distribution $p(x)$ can we state something about the Lipschitz constant of $\tilde{p}(x)$ as a function of $L$ and $\sigma^2$ rather than just the naive bound?

Comment: I don't really know. But note that if $p$ is just a Lipschitz function, not a probability distribution, then the new Lipschitz constant need not be smaller.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich could you give an example, I can try to carry that to the probability setting. One of the notable things is that since the gradient is a linear operator the gradient is also a convolution, and I don't see how the average of a function is not always smaller than the maximum?

Comment: If $p(t)=t$ then $p*f=p$. (When you said "smaller" I assumed you meant "smaller"; $1$ is not smaller than $1$.)

Comment: I see... I guess I meant <=. It is true that for a constant it remains a constant. However, that is not possible for a distribution.

Comment: I believe it _is_ true that if $p$ iis a probability distribution then the Lipshcitz constant for $p*f$ is strictly smaller than that for $p$. _But_ you can have $p(t)=ct$ on long intervals, hence I don't think you can say mmuch about how much smaller...

Comment: I see your point but am not sure I can agree. If $p(t) = ct$ in any region the width of the region is bounded, since the integral of that part of the density must be less than 1 it means that any such regions dependable on $c$ have bounded range, thus for a fixed sigma the Gaussian will pick up things outside of them...

Comment: That's more or less why it seems that you do have strict inequality if $p$ is a distribution. When I said "long" I didn't mean arbitrarily long - you  can get an arbitrarily long interval by taking $c$ small enough. (This shows for example that there is no $a<1$ such that $L'\le aL$, which is an example of what I mean by "can't say much about how much smaller"...)

Comment: Yes, but basically the longer the interval - the smaller the c hence the Lipshitz constant is smaller. Then as well based on the variance of sigma it seems that if that goes to infinity the function will become close to a constant hence the Lipshitz constant should stay the same. The question is what is the decay rate of L as we move sigma from 0 -> infinity and note that this might depend on L in itself.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is as follows for your reference.

Suppose $|\frac{d}{dx}f_0(x)| \le L$, and that there exists Fourier transformation for $f_0(x)$, $f(x) = \int f_0(x - t) N(t; 0, \sigma^2) ~dt$ is its convolution with Gaussian, then $f(x)$ is $L'$ Lipschitz bounded, and $L' \le L$.

Proof:
By Fourier transformation, $f_0(x)$ can be expressed as
$$ f_0(x) = \int F_0(\omega) \exp\{j\omega x\} ~d\omega $$
where $F_0(\omega) = \mathcal{F}[f_0(x)]$. The Fourier transformation of the Gaussian distribution is
$$ \mathcal{F}[N(t; 0, \sigma^2)] = \exp\{-\frac{\sigma^2\omega^2}{2}\}. $$
Thus, we have
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\int f_0(x - t) p(t) ~dt = \int F_0(\omega)  \int \frac{d}{dx}\exp\{j\omega (x-t)\}p(t) ~dt ~d\omega. $$
We can reduce the inner integral part by
$$ \int \frac{d}{dx}\exp\{j\omega (x-t)\}p(t) ~dt = j\omega \int \exp\{j\omega (x-t)\}p(t) ~dt $$
in which the integral part is the convolution of $\exp\{j\omega x\}$ with the Gaussian. In frequency domain, convolution becomes multiplication, and 
$$ \mathcal{F}[\exp\{j\omega_0 x\}] = 2\pi \delta(\omega - \omega_0) $$
where $\delta(\cdot)$ denotes Dirac function. Therefore, we have
$$ |\int \frac{d}{dx}\exp\{j\omega (x-t)\}p(t) ~dt| = |j\omega \exp\{-\frac{\sigma^2\omega^2}{2}\} \exp\{j\omega x\}|. $$

Thus, the norm of the derivative of $f(x)$ is given by
$$|\frac{d}{dx}\int f_0(x - t) p(t) ~dt| = |\int \omega\exp\{j\omega x\} F_0(\omega)\exp\{-\frac{\omega^2\sigma^2}{2}\}~d\omega|.$$
Using the bound of the derivative of $f_0(x)$, we have
$$ |\frac{d}{dx}f_0(x)| = |\int \frac{d}{dx}\exp\{j\omega x\}F_0(\omega)~d\omega| = |\int \omega\exp\{j\omega x\} F_0(\omega)~d\omega| \le L. $$
Because $\exp\{-\frac{\omega^2\sigma^2}{2}\} \le 1$, we can obtain
$$|\int \omega\exp\{j\omega x\} F_0(\omega)\exp\{-\frac{\omega^2\sigma^2}{2}\}~d\omega| \le L. $$